# How to set a text line by line to multi line edit text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a list of names and i need to add those names to multi line edit text box by line by line. But here it is adding only last added name to edit text box.How can i resolve this can any give a suggestion.

Here my code is:

```
 for(int i =0; i<Products.length; i++){

                    etItem.setText(Products[i]);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = "";
for(int i =0; i<Products.length; i++){
  str  += Products[i]+"\n";
}
etItem.setText(str);
```

Comment: Might as well just set the text once after the loop

Comment: Probably also need to add the newline character `\n` too (and time the trailing one after the loop

Comment: It is adding all the names but it is not coming Line by Line. It is coming one after another

Comment: `etItem.setText(str.trim());`

Answer (score 1):

This could be as easy as:

```
etItem.setText(TextUtils.join("\n", Products));
```

You'll probably want to guard this with a `null` check too.

Your own code example sets the text for every product item, overwriting the previous value. Hence, only the last product item will ever display.

Alternatively, an approach that more resembles your original code would be to leverage the [`TextView#append(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)) method. That'll be slightly more code than the one-liner above, as you'll have to ensure there is no line break before the first item (or after the last).